# Why RewriteRule changes port on redirection?

Tags: apache

Virtual host is running *:444;

Having:

```
RewriteRule $ /home/ [B,NE,R,L] //what is that $ here anyway?
```

When I access

```
http://myhost:444/
```

Request results in 302 redirection to

```
http://myhost/home/
```

Why port is changed? How to preserve port? RewriteRule docs says R preserves port but for some reasons it does not for me.

Quoting docs:

> If a fully-qualified URL is specified (that is, including
>   http://servername/) then a redirect will be issued to that location.
>   Otherwise, the current protocol, servername, **and port number** will be
>   used to generate the URL sent with the redirect.

So why port number is not there?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Tell me please what I missed there - I have stated that I know what docs says and it should preserve the port, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

the condition might look alike that:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^444$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:444/$1 [L,R]
```

the `^` and `$` mean `start` and `end` of string, in regex pattern.

while the `$1`, `$2` are regex matches, put into back-references.

Comment: so thats just part of regex here? Is it condition or "how to match url to get valueable parts of it" ?
But anyway, why port is not prepended when docs says it will be preserved? It saysI dont have to use full url.